# How to retrieve values from multiple get calls by setting up multiple providers to the same route being visited to display the valued to the user?

Tags: angular, routes

I am new to Angular and I still have a long way to go. I am trying to retrieve values to display on the front end(by doing form.getvalue) from APIs. The setup is such that values are being retrieved based on the userId in the route.

As soon as the route is hit a resolver linked to the provider is being called which calls a get request from a different component.ts file.

And then the values are being deconstructed using var name = this.route.snapshot.data.name (this is an example).

Now how do I get values from multiple get requests into the same route.data.snapshot call. I tried hooking up multiple providers and resolvers to the same route but, i dont think i did that right.

Any advice will be appreciated.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'something',
  templateUrl: 'something.html',
  styleUrls: ['something.scss']
})
export class EmployeesEditComponent implements OnInit, ComponentOnDeactivate {



  constructor(public store:Store<HeaderViewState>,
              public Employeesinfo: ManageEmployeesServices,
              public formBuilderService: FormBuilderService,
              private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("Inside EmployeesEditComponent ngOnInit()");
    this.states = states();
    this.manageEmployeesForm = 
  this.formBuilderService._buildManageEmployeeForm();

    if(this.route.snapshot.queryParams.searchValue) {
      //this.searchValue = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.searchValue;
    }

    if(this.route.snapshot.queryParams.page) {
      this.page = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.page;
    }


    const {userId: user_id, firstName, middleName, lastName, gender, email, address1, address2 } = userSelf;

    this.manageEmployeesForm.setValue({firstName, middleName, lastName,
      address1, address2, email
     });
```

Routing module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  Route.withShell([{ path: 'manage-employees', component: EmployeesComponent, data: { title: 'Manage Employees' }},
                          { path: 'manage-employees/edit',
                            component: ManageEmployeesEditComponent,
                            data: { title: 'Manage Employees' },
                            canDeactivate: [HeaderEnableGuard],
                            resolve: {userSelf: UserSelfResolver}
                            },
                          ])



];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [UserSelfResolver]
})

export class ManageEmployeesRoutingModule {}
```

The resolver calls one get request. but I want to return multiple get requests to populate the front end form on the same route.

Comment: You can add as many resolvers you want to a route. If you have 3 resolvers at keys a, b and c, you'll have data.a data.b and data.c in the route snapshot.

Comment: but how do i hookup multiple providers in the @Ngmodule ?

Comment: It's an array. You separate the providers with commas: `providers: [UserSelfResolver, Foo, Bar]`. Note that you shouldn't have providers in the first place. Instead, you should have a `providedIn: 'root'` in your Injectable decorator